# Performance hit from using the Statistics module?

Tags: 8, performance

For a site that we will have 99% of users seeing Varnish/Memcached layers, what is the general performance hit to enabling the core Statistics module? The site may have thousands of visitors daily.

Is it best to just not use it at all? I am of the opinion that it is not worth the database activity.

Comment: Yes, this wouldn't be a good idea for a high traffic site. But for a few thousands visits a day I think there is no performance hit at all. The ajax request in the background takes around 20 or 30 ms. You can do the math how many visitors you can handle per day.

Comment: The amount of impact depends on whether your server can scale horizontally or not.

Comment: @NoSssweat, you need to consider scalability when reaching a critical volume and the statistics module probably won't perform very well in this point. So for high traffic (resulting in a significant amount of concurrent requests) you should probably store the statistics data in another place than the drupal database.